# Automating Scheduling for Reading Program in NPSP - Seeking Advice!

Tags: npsp

I'm relatively new to Salesforce, and I'm working with a nonprofit to customize their NPSP for a reading program. As part of this effort, I'm building a flow to automate the registration of both students and volunteers. However, I'm facing a challenge with automating the scheduling process.

Currently, during registration, students need to select weekly time slots that work for them. They are provided with multiple 30-minute options between 4 PM and 6:30 PM from Monday to Thursday. Additionally, volunteers are manually matched based on their availability during these time slots.The students and volunteers are stored as distinct record types.

I'm seeking guidance from the community on how to automate the scheduling aspect using NPSP. If anyone has experience solving a similar problem for their organization, I'd love to hear about the approaches you've used. I'm open to trying out different ideas to find a scalable and automated solution.

The nonprofit manages around 100-120 students and an equal number of volunteers, making the manual scheduling process time-consuming and resource-intensive. An automated solution would greatly benefit the organization, allowing them to focus on other important tasks and expand the program to accommodate the numerous students eagerly waiting for support.

Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.